# No USB boot option after boot repair ;

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, usb, boot-repair

No boot option from USB is showing up at startup

i have boot-repaired when dual booting my system with windows and ubuntu . But in order to boot again from  usb , no option is available in BIOS .

Only ubuntu is shown as number 1

1- Ubuntu

how to gain usb boot option back ?